# Change position of div with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I am trying to make an animation with a div using css and javascript. I want to make all the content in the div go down 800 pixels in 6 seconds on a click. This is what I have so far. Thanks.

```js
var firstVar = window.document.body;

function gone() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.top = "800px";  
}

firstVar.addEventListener("click", gone);
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  transition: top 6s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>
      <marquee class="bouncy" direction="down" width="1000" height="200" behavior="alternate" style="border: solid">
        <marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="40">
          Sean's Web App Space 
        </marquee>
      </marquee>
    </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You forgot to share your code.

Comment: Please add the code as an edit to your question so that it is obvious for anyone looking at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `top: 0;` so that it has an initial value to animate from. `auto` is the default value and you cannot animate from auto => 800px so you need to provide an initial value of 0.

```js
var firstVar = window.document.body;

function gone() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.top = "800px";  
}

firstVar.addEventListener("click", gone);
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 6s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>
      <marquee class="bouncy" direction="down" width="1000" height="200" behavior="alternate" style="border: solid">
        <marquee behavior="alternate" scrollamount="40">
          Sean's Web App Space 
        </marquee>
      </marquee>
    </h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think its going like this:

1. The page loads and the CSS rules run instantly.
2. Your Javascript runs whenever you happen to click.  The CSS rules don't do anything because the classes/ids/elements on the page didn't change.

Solution: when you click, add a new class to the element - that will trigger CSS to re-render.  That new class should have these css rules:

```
top: 800px;
transition: top 6s;
```

Comment: When I do this, it jumps from it's position to 800 pixels down, it doesn't smoothly animate. New JS code:

Comment: `document.getElementById("main").style.top = "800px";
           document.getElementById("main").style.transition="top 6s";`